# Go from 2*2 table to long date format in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Any idea how I can generate dates for all occurrences of the different cell values in the following table?

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Edit:
Monday in week1 is 04.01.21

Comment: There is a missing piece.  We need to know the exact date of **Mon  Week1**

Comment: Sorry--see edit-

Comment: Are Monday and Friday in the first row merged cells?

Comment: Yes—borg Friday, Wednesday and Monday are merged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1] Set up a criteria with Qty column in Col N and Col O

2] In "Qty" `O2`, formula copied down :

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:I$5,N2)
```

3] In "Individual" `K2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(N$2:N$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(N$2:N$4)-ROW(N$1)/(O$2:O$4>=COLUMN($1:$1)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

4] In "Date", `L2` formula Copied down :

```
=44193+SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(A$1:A$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$5)/(B$2:I$5=K2),COUNTIF(K$2:K2,K2))),"Week","")*7+LOOKUP(MOD(AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($2:$5)/1%+{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})/(B$2:I$5=K2),COUNTIF(K$2:K2,K2)),100),{2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},{0;0;1;2;2;3;4;4})
```

Remark :

44193 (28/12/2020) being the Monday of last week number of year 2020,

then

Convert week number to date in the year of 2021 become >>

=44193 + WeekNumber x 7 + (0 to 4 being Mon to Fri)

[image]